Domain network dropping
We have a domain environment. One DC, 3 switches.
IP .15 – FS Switch has voice = 172 and Data = 173 - VLANS
IP .16 – FS Switch has voice = 172 and Data = 173 - VLANS
.117 – HP switch has voice = 1 VLAN
Our network is dropping intermediately, phone and data. Nothing has changed, except we got VOIP a few months prior.
We have done the following: Restart domain, checked DHCP, DNS - restarted all switches, checked for ARP traffic, checked all inbound / outbound traffic. Firewall settings etc. A lot more that I can’t think of
I have tried every possible solution to this, yet I can’t get it to stop.
Possible solutions: the HP switch does not have the correct VLANS to communicate with the other switches, but still pulls the right IP on the devices.
HP switch is going bad.
Ask any question, I’m just getting a headache

Domain name dropping is not exactly descriptive. However, perhaps a device on the network has the same IP address as the DC.
